# Why I still can not use Postgis function after install the Postgis extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Well as clear as the title, my college set up the database and said that already add Postgis extension to the database.

[image]

However, I still can not use the function of Postgis

```
ERROR: function routing.st_distancesphere(unknown, text) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 47
```

Comment: "You might need to add explicit type casts".  Did you try that?

Comment: ^^ Especially since it appears the first argument is an `unknown` type. That's going to make it hard for postGIS to know what to do with it

Comment: Check if the function exists in the schema. There is an implicit type cast from `text` to `geometry`, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Can you show us the query that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following to confirm if you have postgis installed

```
SELECT PostGIS_version();
```

If not installed then you can install it with

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```